# failing to install RVM while trying to install RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, curl

I am trying to install RoR on my system. I am following [digital ocean's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) tutorial. While I try to install RVM `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` with this command I am getting the below error:

> gpg: Signature made Tuesday 31 March 2015 03:22:13 AM IST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
>   gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
>   Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
>   Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).
>
> GPG signature verification failed for
>   '/home/suraj/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11.tgz' -
>   'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc'!
>   try downloading the signatures:
>
> gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys
>   409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
>
> or if it fails:

```
command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
```

the key can be compared with:

```
https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
```

I tried to add the key manually with no success. someone please help me out here.

Comment: What happens when you run gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 ?

Comment: `gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
`

This is what I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still facing this issue, it only works for me when I replace "gpg" with "gpg2":

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```